# print file side by side in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, printing

Dear experts i have a programme that callulate x and y and print x and y by the command print(x,y) as follows

```
[2.63732473e-002 6.95547303e-005 1.83437361e-007 4.83776370e-010
 1.27583713e-012 3.36458575e-015 8.87257918e-018 2.33965401e-020
 6.16901626e-023 1.62648985e-025 4.28780820e-028 1.13020771e-030]
[2.97870294e-033 7.84889062e-036 2.06774505e-038 5.44613117e-041
 1.43405459e-043 3.77498976e-046 9.93370767e-049 2.61308006e-051
 6.16901626e-023 1.62648985e-025 4.28780820e-028 1.13020771e-030]
```

but i want to print x and y in just two column as follows

```
  x                        y
2.63732473e-002          2.97870294e-033
6.95547303e-005          7.84889062e-036
1.83437361e-007          2.06774505e-038
4.83776370e-010          5.44613117e-041
1.27583713e-012          1.43405459e-043 
3.36458575e-015          3.77498976e-046
8.87257918e-018          9.93370767e-049
2.33965401e-020          2.61308006e-051
6.16901626e-023          6.16901626e-023 
1.62648985e-025          1.62648985e-025 
4.28780820e-028          4.28780820e-028
1.13020771e-030          1.13020771e-030
```

However i tried `print(str(x[:,None]),str(y[:,None]))` but it still print vertically instead of side by side.hope some expert will help me.Thanks.

Comment: also if you want some fancy output (in grid for example) take a look at https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and [join](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.join#str.join):

> Use str.format() on a number with "{:e}" as str to format the number in scientific notation.

```py
print("\n".join(f"{i:e}   {j:e}" for i, j in zip(x, y)))
```

Comment: i want to save the output, how can i save instead of print

Comment: you can write the string to a file with: `with open(PATH_TO_FILE, "w") as f: f.write("\n".join(f"{i:e}   {j:e}" for i, j in zip(x, y)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\t` to format a tabbing. For example:

```
print("%d\t\t%d" % (x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

> print(x,y,'\n')

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is iterate simultaneously on both lists and print  the equivalent field like so:

```
print(f'x        y')
for i in range(len(x)):
   print(f'{x[i]}        {y[i]}')
```